# sorting dictionary values asc in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python which is look like this :

```
{'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd6', 'd7'], 'Term2': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'], 'Term3': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd5', 'd6', 'd77'], 'Term4': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd16', 'd17', 'd77'], 'Term5': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd10', 'd22'], 'Term6': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd17', 'd55', 'd77'], 'Term7': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd2', 'd7', 'd22'], 'Term8': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd14', 'd66', 'd88'], 'Term9': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd2', 'd77', 'd88'], 'Term10': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd44', 'd77'], 'Term11': [6, 'd1', 'd15', 'd46', 'd57', 'd66', 'd88'], 'Term12': [3, 'd2', 'd7', 'd66'], 'Term13': [3, 'd4', 'd44', 'd77'], 'Term14': [3, 'd55', 'd66', 'd88']}
```

key : values

I need to make d's in the list sorted.. smth like :

```
'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd4' 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd43'] ... etc
```

I tried to do :

```
','.join(sorted(values, key=lambda x: int(x[1:])))
```

where values are `intermediate_dictionary[term]`

but i entered in infinte loop , and it's not working ...

this is my full code where I create the `self.final_inverted_index`:

```
  for term in intermediate_dictionary.keys():
        intermediate_dictionary[term].insert(0, len(intermediate_dictionary[term]))
        self.final_inverted_index[term] = intermediate_dictionary[term]
```

Comment: You trying to sort a list, not a dictionary

Comment: Does your dictionary look exactly as presented? It would mean that it contains a string and not a list.

Comment: The value looks like a string, but is actually a syntax error. Please update your question with your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the values into the int and string, sort the strings and concatenate with the int. If you use key function for sort, you can get an actual number sorting instead of standard dictionary sorting for strings:

```
d = {'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd6', 'd7']}

d = {k: [v[0]] + sorted(v[1:], key = lambda x: int(x[1:])) for k, v in d.items()}

print(d)
```

Non in-place version:

```
d = {'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd6', 'd7']}

new_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    new_d[k] = [d[k][0]] + sorted(v[1:], key = lambda x: int(x[1:]))

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
d = {'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd5', 'd43', 'd4', 'd6', 'd7']}

for k in d.keys():
    d[k].sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1:]) if isinstance(x, str) else 0)
```

Output:

```
{'Term1': [6, 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd43']}
```